# Split values in array in ordered columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[image]

And I want to create new columns based on how the values of the list end. If value in list ends in "na" send the full value "banana" to a new column "Bananas". If the value ends in "go" send the full value "mango" to a new column "Mangos".

I have tried splitting the columns in excel by delimiter comma and creating new columns but it does not work.

Any idea on how this can be achieved in python?

Best,
Claudiu

Comment: what you're trying to do is move each fruit into a column with the fruit name capitalized? what is the expected behavior when there are two of a fruit?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 
I simplified the example. My use case is a df with column "assets" storing lists such as ['http://g1.jpg','http://g3.jpg','http://g2.jpg','http://g4.jpg'] and I want to create g1 column storing g1 links, g2 column storing g2 links and so on. I intend to do the search by the end of the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```py
tmp = df.explode('favorite_fruits')
```

This will explode your lists and write its content as rows like so:

```py
      name  age favorite_fruits
0    tammy    6          banana
0    tammy    6           mango
0    tammy    6          orange
0    tammy    6      watermelon
1    bonny    8           apple
1    bonny    8            pear
1    bonny    8           peach
2    helga    8             NaN
3      tom   10          banana
3      tom   10        maracuja
3      tom   10      watermelon
3      tom   10           apple
3      tom   10       pineapple
4   jerome    7      strawberry
4   jerome    7       raspberry
4   jerome    7       blueberry
5     hans    9       blueberry
5     hans    9      watermelon
5     hans    9           apple
5     hans    9       raspberry
6     lisa   10           mango
6     lisa   10       pineapple
6     lisa   10          orange
7    trish    6      watermelon
7    trish    6           apple
7    trish    6       blueberry
7    trish    6            pear
7    trish    6      strawberry
8    steve    8            pear
8    steve    8      strawberry
8    steve    8       raspberry
9  antoine    5           peach
9  antoine    5      strawberry
9  antoine    5           apple
9  antoine    5       blueberry
```

Afterward you specify the regex filter pattern and use named capturing groups and extract these patterns into new columns (`expand=True`)

```py
mangos = '(?P<Mangos>.*go$)'
bananas = '(?P<Bananas>.*na$)'
oranges = '(?P<Oranges>.*ge$)'
watermelons = '(?P<Watermelons>.*on$)'
apples = '(?P<Apples>.*le$)'
maracujas = '(?P<Maracujas>.*ja$)'
peaches = '(?P<Peaches>.*ch$)'
raspberries = '(?P<Raspberries>.*ry$)'
pears = '(?P<Pears>.*ar$)'


tmp = tmp['favorite_fruits'].str.extract(
    '|'.join([mangos, bananas, oranges, watermelons, apples, maracujas, peaches, raspberries, pears]),
    expand=True
)

# groupie is used to write the entries all in on row
res = tmp.groupby(tmp.index).first()
df = pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)
```

The finished df will then look like this

```py
      name  age  ... Raspberries Pears
0    tammy    6  ...        None  None
1    bonny    8  ...        None  pear
2    helga    8  ...        None  None
3      tom   10  ...        None  None
4   jerome    7  ...  strawberry  None
5     hans    9  ...   blueberry  None
6     lisa   10  ...        None  None
7    trish    6  ...   blueberry  pear
8    steve    8  ...  strawberry  pear
9  antoine    5  ...  strawberry  None
```